# How to retrieve rich text numbered in my Strapi cms to my ui

Tags: flutter

"list": [
{
"type": "list",
"format": "ordered",
"children": [
{
"type": "list-item",
"children": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "We import the necessary packages. Make sure to add http to your pubspec.yaml file."
}
]
},
{
"type": "list-item",
"children": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "We define the URL where we want to send the POST request."
}
]
},
{
"type": "list-item",
"children": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "We define the data we want to send. It's typically a Map, but it can be any data structure."
}
]
},
{
"type": "list-item",
"children": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "We encode the data to JSON format using json.encode."
}
]
},

How to call this in my flutter project and use richtext to create the ui in flutter.

I don't know what to do